# SQL choose rows with the largest value in a column

Tags: sql

I am making a library database. I have a column called "ArriveDate", and the dates are strings in the format MM/DD/YYYY (month and day might be single digit).

I want to find the new arrivals, so I need to find all books with the largest ArriveDate. I don't have any knowledge of SQL, so any help is appreciated!

Example table:
**title, author, ArriveDate**

```
Harry Potter 1, J.K. Rowling, 7/1/2020
Harry Potter 2, J.K. Rowling, 7/1/2020
Harry Potter 3, J.K. Rowling, 7/1/2020
Book Title 1, Author Name 1, 6/1/2020
Book Title 2, Author Name 2, 6/1/2020
Magazine 1, Author Name 3, 6/1/2020
```

Expected result:
**title, author, ArriveDate**

```
Harry Potter 1, J.K. Rowling, 7/1/2020
Harry Potter 2, J.K. Rowling, 7/1/2020
Harry Potter 3, J.K. Rowling, 7/1/2020
```

Here, 7/1/2020 is the largest date

To clarify, I'm stuck because the dates are stored as strings. If there was a way to convert them into SQL dates, I would know how to go from there.

Comment: Fix your table!  Do not store dates as a string!  Store dates using the built-in data types.

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we will help you debug your code after you make an attempt. If you don't have any knowledge of SQL, this might not be the place to start learning.

Comment: If you store your date as a date data type, finding the most recent date should be simple

Comment: I can't change how the date is stored. It's used in so many places that changing it is not my call. I am stuck because the dates are strings. If they were actual dates, then I would just use MAX and it would be easy.

Comment: "the dates are strings"  Probably this is the thing you should change.  `DateTime` type is created for a reason.

Comment: How does your database record multiple authors for a book?

Comment: "I can't change how the date is stored"  Then you are stuck.  How can you do date arithmetic with a string???

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you should probably fix your table to store dates properly. If you are stuck with your current table setup, you could try `Cast('7/1/2020' as datetime)` and order that way, then you could use a Common Table Expression to grab the top one, via a partition statement.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments, but is the same that Tarik, with sample from mysql...

SELECT *
FROM Table1
where dateold = (select max(dateold) from table1)

Please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49f657/25

Comment: This will definitely not work!

Comment: @Tarik In conclusion, the solution doesn't work, thus the downvote.  I don't downvote people's post for no reason.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a subquery. Something like

```
select * from mytable where CONVERT(varchar, arrdate, 1) = (select max(CONVERT(varchar, arrdate, 1)) from mytable)
```

This is a link to a similar question: [How to use MAX() on a subquery result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182700/how-to-use-max-on-a-subquery-result)

Comment: This will definitely not work!