# Find the Max Value in a list of rows and return the whole row SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to figure out how to return one row from a table that has the highest value in a column. Before I can do that I have to take a substring of that column and convert it to an INT.

The Main table name is "CalendarPeriod"

Here is an example of the column

FiscalPeriod - 0120

I have to take the two characters from the left, which will be the number I am trying to find the MAX value of

Below is a list of the rows with there column Names. FiscalPeriod is the Column that I need to Substring and Cast to an Int to find the max value.

[image]

The result of this query should return return the row with the FiscalPeriod "1220" with the Id being "1134", but it is returning the first one.

Here is the query that I found, but I am having trouble trying to figure out how to convert that back to the NVARCHAR. I though that If I added the regular Fiscal Period inside the inner join I would be able to use that in the Where Clause to get the max value, but I was wrong.

I also am Inner Joining another Table "CalendarPeriodHeader" which has the year which I will also need for a comparison in the where. This might be messing up the query results as well, but I am stumped Below is the query I have so far.

```
Select Top 1 cp.*
From CalendarPeriod as cp
INNER JOIN
(
    Select  Top 1 Id, Max(Cast(Substring(FiscalPeriod, 1,2) as Int)) as MAXFiscal, FiscalPeriod
    From CalendarPeriod 
    Group By Id, FiscalPeriod
    
)cp2
On cp2.Id = cp.Id
Inner Join CalendarPeriodHeader as header on header.Id = cp.HeaderId
Where cp2.FiscalPeriod = cp.FiscalPeriod And header.Year = 2020
```

Comment: Using `top` without `order by` is usually problematic.

Comment: find the max, then subquery using it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182700/how-to-use-max-on-a-subquery-result

Comment: @GordonLinoff That might work I don't know why I didn't catch that!

Comment: Why are you storing dates in datetime columns? 2 digit years? Don't start now. Want to sort by fiscal period? Year should come first. Doing that will make your goal much simpler since you can use max aggregate with appropriate filter.

Comment: Have to store dates in a datetime due to the complexity of calendar periods in accounting for example a 52/53 week calendar period the fiscal period 0120 could be April 27,2020 and the 1220 fiscal period could be April 28, 2021

Comment: @GordonLinoff your solution worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this query:
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.CalendarPeriod ORDER BY Cast(Substring(FiscalPeriod, 1,2) as Int) DESC